# Jquery on 'keyup' not binding

Tags: jquery

This seems fine to me, however only the change event is firing. I could bind the events separately but I shouldn't have to, what have I missed?

```
$('.js_EmailSupplier_Search, .js_EmailSupplier_Supplier').unbind('keyup change');
$('.js_EmailSupplier_Search, .js_EmailSupplier_Supplier').on('keyup change', function () {

    const search = $('.js_EmailSupplier_Search').val().toLowerCase();
    const supplierId = $('.js_EmailSupplier_Supplier').val();

    $('.js_EmailSupplier_Row').each(function () {
        $(this).removeAttr("style");

        if (supplierId !== "-1") {
            if ($(this).attr('data-supplier-id') !== supplierId)
                $(this).hide();
        }

        if (search !== "") {
            if ($(this).attr('data-search').toLowerCase().indexOf(search) === -1)
                $(this).hide();
        }
    });

});
```

**Edit** I should add that 'js_EmailSupplier_Search' is a textbox, and 'js_EmailSupplier_Supplier' is a select. Could this be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event binding works... Since you did not provide all the HTML parts linked to the problem, I was receiving javascript errors but that shouldn't be your problem.

```js
$('.js_EmailSupplier_Search, .js_EmailSupplier_Supplier').unbind('keyup change');
$('.js_EmailSupplier_Search, .js_EmailSupplier_Supplier').on('keyup change', function() {

  console.log("event fired");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="js_EmailSupplier_Supplier">
```